# Por que no se ejecuta mi javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

En mi codigo de index.html no tengo nada más que el `<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>` antes del closing del body . En el main.js tengo el siguiente ejercicio que encontré en MDN

```
var miImage = document.querySelector('img');

miImage.onclick = function () {
    var miSrc = miImage.getAttribute('src');
    if (miSrc === 'images/firefox-icon.png') {
      miImage.setAttribute('src','images/firefox2.png');
    } else {
      miImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/firefox-icon.png');
    }
}
```

Tengo una carpeta con las imagenes del mismo tamaño en png . En el momento de abrir el index.html no aparece nada .

Comment: Perdon. Se borró esto. En el index.html solo tengo <script src="scripts/main.js"></script> antes del closing del body

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: No solo deberías agregar tu código HTML, deberías revisar por consola si la función que asignas al evento `onclick` de tu elemento se está ejecutando, para ello existe el objeto `console` y todos sus métodos: `log(), info(), error(), etc.`. De esta forma podrás depurar tu código y saber donde podría estar el error. Pista: *tal vez el elemento `miImage` aún no es totalmente cargado en memoria cuando se ejecuta el script*. Sería recomendable que ejecutaras el mismo dentro de una función como [*window.onload*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload). Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Si dices que en tu `index` solo tienes `<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>` el JS no encuentra el elemento `img` en tu index. Si es esto solo agrega un elemento `<img></img>` para que el JS lo encuentre. Te recomiendo al igual que los demás, si pones el HTML será más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score -1):

Para que funcione el código en javascript, es necesario cargar el DOM (Document Object Model) con "$(document).ready(function(){...})", por lo que el archivo main.js iría de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var miImage = document.querySelector('#firefoxImage');

    miImage.onclick = function () {
        var miSrc = miImage.getAttribute('src');
        if (miSrc === 'images/firefox-icon.png') {
          miImage.setAttribute('src','images/firefox2.png');
        } else {
          miImage.setAttribute('src','images/firefox-icon.png');
        }
    }
})
```

y el código en index.html sería el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="firefoxImage" src="images/firefox2.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Es mejor asignarle un "id" al elemento "img", para que en main.js en el "querySelector" se pueda seleccionar por id, y así podremos controlar la imagen que deseemos (en caso de que haya más elementos con la etiqueta "img").

Comment: no es para cargar el DOM, es para verificar si el DOM ya se termino de cargar https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el OP, utiliza javascript, y no JQuery, tu respuesta esta incompleta al no indicar que es JQuery y como agregarlo a un proyecto, confundes mas al OP al no hacer una respuesta completa. -1.